# How to add an image below the header on homepage

Tags: images, headers, homepage

Thanks in advance for the help.

I just activated the Astra theme and have created a child for customization.
I want an image between the header and content sections. Similar to the twentyseventeen theme but with a fixed header at the top.

For whatever reason, my header image shows when I use the twentyseventeen theme, but not on any other themes.

I have FileZilla and NotePad++ installed.

My coding level is definitely beginner. I am learning HTML as I go, so I know basic style and attribute code. I am also getting to the point where I can read the code tree pretty well.

Comment: My website is [www.rosskline.com](http://www.rosskline.com)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the hook `astra_content_before` to add the image to the content before. Eg.

```
add_action( 'astra_content_before', 'astra_child_theme_image_before_content' );

function astra_child_theme_image_before_content() {
   // Code here
}
```